# Are questions about "location which has the best X" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Suppose I want to know what the best location in the world, or in some region, is. Naturally, I am using some objective definition for "best", to make sure the question has an answer. For example,

> Which summit in the Alps above 4000 m is the closest to a place which I can reach with a 4x4 drive vehicle?

or

> Where is the world's longest non-technical scramble of average steepness more than 30°?

It seems on topic, but could be problematic to answer if not obvious, and problematic to verify. Also, usefulness of such questions may be limited, but also may be too broad, making them more suitable for the Wikipedia.

So, are such questions on-topic here?

Answer (score 2):

The "best" of anything is always going to carry a lot of opinion.  Simply asking for the best place to do something should be off-topic with the standard close reason "Primarily Opinion Based".

But your two quoted examples don't use the word "best".  They could concievably be definitively answered.  Although, as you suggest, that may be problematic.

I suspect that it is impossible to draw a hard line between on- and off-topic questions of this nature.  Each question will have to be evaluated individually.

Comment: I didn't want to ask about opinion-based questions. I added a clarification to my question.

Comment: I just took "best" from your question title.